Limit of gradient of smooth functions
Let us consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. Decompose $\mathbb{R}^n=\cup_{i=1}^n U_i$, where $U_i$ are each closed, convex cones. Further assume $f\vert_{U_i}=T_i$ is a linear functional, this shown in particular $f$ is positively homogeneous. I can construct smooth, positively homogeneous functions $f_t$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ as follows : Pick a family $g_t:S^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}$ of smooth functions, which uniformly converge to $f\vert_{S^{n-1}}$. Then define $$f_t(x) =\|x\|g_t\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)$$
Then $f_t$ are also positively homogeneous, smooth functions, which converge to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$, uniformly on compact sets.
Now if I understand correctly, $f$ has a weak gradient, $\nabla f(x)=T_i$ restricted to $U_i$, here I'm considering the $T_i$ as elements of the dual vector space. Can anything be said about $\nabla f_t(x)$ when $x\in U_i$?
The example I'm thinking of is the function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, given by $f(x,y)=\max(x,y,0)$. There are three cones in this case, $U_1=[x, y\le 0], U_2=[x\ge 0, x\ge y], U_3=[y\ge 0, y\ge x]$. The gradient is constant in each of the cones, taking values $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)$ respectively. If I just mollify the function, restrict to the sphere and then homogenize again, then that gives a family $f_t$. But it's not clear to me what the derivative becomes. Thank you for any help.
